# systemd yocto recipe for an existing executable

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm looking for a template recipe for enabling a systemd recipe in yocto. The executable is already installed by a recipe provided by yocto. The goal of this recipe is to provide make `/usr/bin/btattach` be run at startup.

As a start I created the following structure in my layer in the appropriate recipe directory:

```
btattach-systemd/
|-- files
|   `-- btattach.service
`-- btattach-systemd.bb
```

The content of the recipe

```
SUMMARY = "Writes patterns to the fb device"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

inherit systemd

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= "systemd"

SRC_URI = "file://btattach.service"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install () {    
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/btattach.service.service ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system
 }

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "btattach.service"
```

Besides that, the `IMAGE_INSTALL` in the image recipe has been correctly extended with `btattach-systemd`.

`bitbake btattach-systemd` runns ok but when trying to build the complete image the at `do_rootfs` step for the whole image.   with the error:

```
 * opkg_solver_install: Cannot install package btattach-systemd.
```

Ideas on where the bug is?

Answer (score 1):

I think the recipe should look like this (leaving out summary, license, license checksum, and assuming that the binary package is called "btattach"):

```
SRC_URI = "file://btattach.service"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "btattach.service"

inherit systemd

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
    for service in ${SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN}}; do
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/${service} ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/

        sed -i -e 's,@BINDIR@,${bindir},g' ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/${service}
    done
}

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "btattach"
```

Comment: This seems to try and install all packages registered under `SYSTEMD_SERVICE`? Not sure that is my problem. Could you pls elaborate a bit?

Comment: Yes it tries to do that, of course you can also limit that to one file manually. As you're not giving more details at the moment (check the logs!), my personal guess is that you're messing up the pathes somehow. Please have a good look at the systemd_unitdir references in the example I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for not commenting your question as I have no reputation for that. Also, [LetoThe2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47222319/1977375) is more complete than mine, but here follows a possible quick fix:

It seems to me you are installing `'btattach.service.service'` instead of `'btattach.service'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the .service file is correct, my take on the Yocto recipe and why it might be failing is because that the btattach.service file isn't included with the installation which is what the final line does below.

Have you ensured that you do a `bitbake btattach.systemd -c cleanall` and `bitbake btattach.systemd -c cleanstate` beforehand as well, as I noticed you had a typo in the Yocto recipe as `btattach.service.service`.

```
SUMMARY = "Writes patterns to the fb device"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

inherit systemd

REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES= "systemd"

SRC_URI = "file://btattach.service"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install () {    
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/btattach.service ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system
}

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "btattach.service"

FILES_${PN} += "/lib/systemd/system/btattach.service"
```